# RabbitMQ exchange bind replicating messages published to one exchange across two other exchanges

Tags: binding, rabbitmq, amqp, messagebroker, rabbitmq-exchange

I have 3 different exchanges in my rabbitMQ i am trying to route all the messages sent to **mainex** across the other two exchanges **dmyex** and **monex** i tried to use the channel.exchngeBind method to bind the exchanges.

I am still not able to see the messages published to mainex going to dmyex and monex.

Is this possible in RabbitMq?

Is there any mistake in what i am doing here?

```
ch.exchangeDeclare("mainex", DIRECT_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
ch.exchangeDeclare("dmyex", CONSISTENT_HASH_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
ch.exchangeDeclare("monex", CONSISTENT_HASH_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
ch.exchangeBind("dmyex","mainex","abcd_KEY");
ch.exchangeBind("monex","mainex","abcd_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the below model is working.

`````
   ch.exchangeDeclare("mainex", DIRECT_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
   ch.exchangeDeclare("dmyex", CONSISTENT_HASH_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
   ch.exchangeDeclare("mongoex", CONSISTENT_HASH_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
   
   
   ch.exchangeBind("dmyex","mainex", "abcd_KEY");
   ch.exchangeBind("monex","mainex", "abcd_KEY");
   
   
   for (String q : Arrays.asList("sharding: dmyex - rabbit@node1 - 0", "sharding: dmyex - rabbit@node2 - 0","sharding: dmyex - rabbit@node3 - 0","sharding: dmyex - rabbit@node4 - 0","sharding: dmyex - rabbit@node5 - 0","sharding: dmyex - rabbit@node6 - 0")) {
       ch.queueBind(q, "dmyex", "1");
   }
   
   
   for (String q : Arrays.asList("sharding: mongoex - rabbit@node1 - 0", "sharding: mongoex - rabbit@node2 - 0","sharding: mongoex - rabbit@node3 - 0","sharding: mongoex - rabbit@node4- 0","sharding: mongoex - rabbit@node5 - 0","sharding: mongoex - rabbit@node6 - 0")) {
       ch.queueBind(q, "mongoex", "1");
   }
   
   
     AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder bldr = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     ch.basicPublish("mainex", "abcd_KEY", bldr.build(), "TestMessage".getBytes("UTF-8"));````
`````

Answer (score 0):

I think that the exchange `mainex` will need to be a Topic exchange in order for wildcard routing to work, as Direct exchanges do their routing based on exact matching of the routing key. Per this [CloudAMQP blog post on exchange types and routing](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html):

> A direct exchange delivers messages to queues based on a message routing key. The routing key is a message attribute added to the message header by the producer. Think of the routing key as an "address" that the exchange is using to decide how to route the message. **A message goes to the queue(s) with the binding key that exactly matches the routing key of the message.**

(This is also touched on in [this answer to a question about wildcard routing keys on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106481/1865611))

That *should* be enough to get your routing working. Perhaps even more simply, if you are going to match any routing key for all of your exchanges that are bound to `mainex`, you could just make `mainex` a Fanout exchange.

Comment: Thank you for your response greg, I tried this using the specific routing keys i am able see the messages in mainex exchange when i publish with "grid" routing key but these same messages are not going to dmyex and monex.

Comment: Do you have queues bound to the exchanges @RajeshBabu?

Comment: Yes i have a shard policy on the consistent hash exchanges dmyex and monex and have 2 shards per node on the cluster.